# Making Future based API wrappers around Akka perform better (ask is a memory hog)

Tags: scala, asynchronous, akka, actor

I've been playing around with an Akka (v 2.3.8) actor prototype to implement a local cache, and I'm having issues getting it to perform as well as another local cache implementation.

The API of this Akka based local cache returns `Future[_]` instances for operations such as put, get...etc, so it's an async API whereas the other local cache implementation returns V, or void, so it's sync.

Initially, I had opted to use per-request actor with Akka `ask` pattern so that when the per-request actor returns a response, the Future is completed. When running performance tests agains the other local cache implementation, this Akka based approach consumes 3x the amount of memory (350mb vs 1GB) as the local cache implementation, and performs way worse (5x-6x worse). I've noticed there's a lot of short-lived garbage generated by Akka in this approach, and one of the biggest consumers seems to be `java.lang.reflect.Field` instances generated by this stacktrace:

`java.lang.reflect.Field.copy()

   java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.copyField(Field) 
      sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.copyField(Field)
         java.lang.Class.copyFields(Field[])
            java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields()
               akka.actor.ActorCell.lookupAndSetField(Class, Object, String, Object)
                  akka.actor.ActorCell.clearActorCellFields(ActorCell)
                     akka.actor.dungeon.FaultHandling$class.akka$actor$dungeon$FaultHandling$$finishTerminate(ActorCell)
                  akka.actor.ActorCell.setActorFields(Actor, ActorContext, ActorRef)
                     akka.actor.ActorCell.clearActorFields(Actor)`

Essentially, seems like an Actor's fields are cleared when it terminates, but if you're using a per-request actor, this seems to create a lot of garbage.

I've also tried another approach where I get rid of the per-request actor, and instead, the message that I pass to the hierarchy supervisor contains a Promise. When the supervisor receives a response from the laywers down, it completes the Promise. This approach generates a lot less garbage, and in fact, it consumes roughly the same memory as the other local cache implementation. However, it still does not perform. The CPU for the Akka based prototype with this new approach shows being used at roughly 60%.

With some thread dumps I realised that completing the Promise is a slow process, and the supervisor seems unable to cope with the amount of requests coming this way, so you see a lot of these stacktraces in the thread dumps:

`"System-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6" #23 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fb4b0428800 nid=0x17c1 runnable [0x00007fb512312000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.unpark(Native Method)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.unpark(LockSupport.java:141)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.unparkSuccessor(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:662)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doReleaseShared(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:689)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.releaseShared(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1342)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$CompletionLatch.apply(Promise.scala:73)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$CompletionLatch.apply(Promise.scala:67)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.processBatch$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:63)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:78)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:54)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.unbatchedExecute(Future.scala:599)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$class.execute(BatchingExecutor.scala:106)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.execute(Future.scala:597)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:248)
    at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.complete(Promise.scala:55)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:153)
    at actor.LocalActorSupervisor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(LocalActorSupervisor.scala:38)`

So, the question is this: Are there any other approaches to improving performance for a `Future[_]` based API wrapping Akka? In other words, how can promise instances be completed in such way that is fast and does not hog down memory? Any ideas?

Comment: Regarding the slowness of the Akka based implementation: Is the performance hit maybe related that the cache retrieval happens in a single actor (and therefore thread). While the synchronous implementation might access the cache multi threaded?

Comment: Without looking at code. it is impossible to say anything concrete. In my personal experience, akka is quite fast and can take about a million messages per second. Moreover, it is alright to have a new actor take a message (`spray`does it). But then the actors can be light weight actors for finetuning performance.

Comment: If by 'synchronous local cache' you mean something like `ConcurrentHashMap` or Guava's `LoadingCache`, that probably will outperform an Actor implementation in memory and speed.  If you wrap the synchronous impl to provide async semantics like the Actor cache, performance will drop, and that's a better comparison.
But - you should share code before we can really discuss..